# Not able to save image to MySQL using android apps

Tags: php, android

I created a PHP script that allows me to save image came from an HTML page(form POST) in a MySQL database, and it is well done, I can see rows in the table and also I can display them in the browser using another PHP script called **load_image_from_db.php** . However, when it comes to saving images via android application, there is some trouble.

I can upload image to MySQL Database using android application, the images are saved, I can see them in the table in PHPmyAdmin, but when i try to show them using the same php script **load_image_from_db.php** they are not displayed (a small emty rectangle is shown).

I figured out that when I save the image via Form.html it takes 32Kio and when I save the same image via android apps it takes 105 Kio in phpMyAdmin(all images are approximately *3.

I will post the java code I used to save image into a MySQL DB :

```
public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}

 @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            Bitmap bitmap = params[0];
            String uploadImage = getStringImage(bitmap);

            HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put(UPLOAD_KEY, uploadImage);

            String result = rh.sendPostRequest(UPLOAD_URL, data);

            return result;
        }
    }

    UploadImage ui = new UploadImage();
    ui.execute(bitmap);
```

**RequestHandler Class :**

```
public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL,
                              HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {

    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(requestURL);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);


        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            response = br.readLine();
        } else {
            response = "Error Registering";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}

private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();


}
```

**upload_image.php**

```html
<?php

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","othmane");
  
  $image = $_POST['image'];
  
  $sql = "INSERT INTO images (image) VALUES (?)";

  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,$sql);
  
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$image);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  
  $check = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
  
  if($check == 1){
   echo "Image Uploaded Successfully";
  }else{
   echo "Error Uploading Image";
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
 }else{
  echo "Error";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php if it's PHP/MySQL issue.

Comment: does my script contains error could you help please ?